# Is this use of the word "concomitant" natural? What other words can be used?

Tags: word-usage

From [a clinical trial synopsis](http://www.trials.boehringer-ingelheim.com/public/trial_results_documents/1239/1239.1_U10-3263-01_DR.pdf) (Boehringer Ingelheim 1239.1):

> Dose: Starting dose of 150 mg b.i.d. (twice daily) BIBF 1120, followed by dose escalation of 50 mg for successive cohorts, up to a maximum of 250 mg b.i.d. (**concomitant** with BIBW 2992)

BIBF 1120 and BIBW 2992 are names of drugs. Is the word "concomitant" felicitous here, or is it better to use **simultaneously with**? What other naturally-sounding alternatives could there be?

I thought that we use "concomitant" when something happens by itself, but here the study authors chose to use this combination of drugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> concomitant

has a specific clinical meaning which goes beyond "simultaneously", it means two *things* have a **relationship** with each other, it can be used for application as well as observed related side-effects.

In your example BIBF 1120 and BIBW 2992 are both kinase inhibitors and so both are meant to be applied together (**interrelated**) in order to shutdown that biological pathway necessary for angiogenesis.

Comment: So the authors went for this word with this specific meaning in mind? Thank you. I thought that maybe they chose it because they were not native speakers of English.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to mean **simultaneously with**, and there are no other connections between BIBF 1120 and BIBW 2992, concomitant is not the right word.

The Cambridge dictionary  provides this definition of **Concomitant**: note the words that I have highlighted.

> something that happens with something else **and is connected with it**

So, while it is legitimate to say

> dementia is concomitant with old age

It is not OK to say

> We drank the wine concomitantly with dinner

... unless you really believe that there could be no dinner without wine :-)